# Makemigrations error on model.py

Tags: python, django

I am new on Python and Django. While trying out an example on a book, I did what the book says and created a models file as follows

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('published','Published'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='published')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices = STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')

    class Meta: 
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

When I run the command, `python manage.py makemigrations blog`

Its says `NameError: name 'STATUS_CHOICES' is not defined`

I typed exactly as it is from the book and I am unable to run this command

Comment: Please correct your posts indentation to show reflect your code. (Most like cause of your issue is incorrect indentation)

Comment: same problem here, why we need to focus on indent rather coding in python?

Answer (score 0):

try to indent your code,you must respect coding style:

```
 status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
choices = STATUS_CHOICES,
```

to

```
choices = 'STATUS_CHOICES',
```

You are missing  `''`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of indent and spacing ,anyways after adding default in publish field and code formatting it worked.

The **model.py** is hosted [here](https://github.com/malwareoverflow/JsWebCamSpy/blob/master/models.py) and **DONOT** edit or open in notepad like editor otherwise it will again create spacing, just import in your IDE